# Find highway near waypoint

Tags: here-api

I would like to find the nearest highway (latitude and longitude) of a given position using 'rest'? Is this possible?
The idea is that the user can enter (select) a 'passthrough' waypoint for a route. If the route is from Belgium to France the waypoint would be in Luxemburg to avoid the toll on the French highways. However, the route should use the highways around the waypoint (if possible) instead of passing through the exact coordinate.
I already tried to set the 'TransitRadius' to 5000, but the route is still calculated on the exact waypoint.
[This](https://tce.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=XXX&app_code=XXX&waypoint0=50.86987,2.88513&waypoint1=passThrough!49.6096,6.1034;5000&waypoint2=stopOver!45.7896,4.8656&detail=1&legattributes=none,li,sm&currency=EUR&tollVehicleType=3&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=3&hybrid=0&emissionType=6&height=4.0m&trailerHeight=4.0m&vehicleWeight=9.5t&limitedWeight=40.0t&heightAbove1stAxle=3.5m&passengersCount=1&tiresCount=12&commercial=1&disabledEquipped=0&minimalPollution=0&width=2.2&length=18&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&rollup=none,country;tollsys,country,tollsys,total&alternatives=0&metricsystem=metric&transportmodetype=truck) is my complete call:

In the image, I displayed the route around the waypoint. The thin red line is the proposed route passing at the waypoint (gray marker), the thick blue line is the route that I want (without detour).

[Map image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SjKM.jpg)

Thx in advance

Comment: Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) tp learn how to create a minimal, reproducible question. Your link does not work by the way

Comment: I know the link does not work, the app_ID and app_Code are like a license key I do not want to publish. If these are replace by an actual ID and Code the link will work

Answer (score 0):

Please check output for the below rest call,

**toll cost 18.2 EUR, travelTime 17:24 h, distance 942 km**

http://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=xxxxx&app_code=xxxxxx&waypoint0=50.86892,2.88533&waypoint1=passThrough!49.6096,6.1034;5000&waypoint2=stopOver!45.7896,4.8656&detail=1&legattributes=none,li,sm&currency=EUR&tollVehicleType=3&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=3&hybrid=0&emissionType=6&height=4.0m&trailerHeight=4.0m&vehicleWeight=9.5t&limitedWeight=40.0t&heightAbove1stAxle=3.5m&passengersCount=1&tiresCount=12&commercial=1&disabledEquipped=0&minimalPollution=0&width=2.2&length=18&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&rollups=none,country;tollsys,country,tollsys,total&alternatives=0&metricsystem=metric&transportmodetype=truck&driver_cost=30

please refer fleet telematics API for more information :

developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html

Comment: I'm sorry but the question was not about toll costs, but about route calculation. I would like to have a route with a pass through waypoint where the truck doesn't leave the highway. The help about transitradius states "For example to drive past a city without necessarily going into the city center you can specify the coordinates of the center and a TransitRadius of 5000m." But I can't seem to get this working, as the truck still leaves the highway to 'pass through' the exact coordinate